# OutletORM and phpDataMapper

Tags: php, orm

I've been playing around with two nice php based ORMs. [OutletORM](http://www.outlet-orm.org/site/) and [phpDataMapper](http://phpdatamapper.com/).

Does anyone have experience with them? Any advantages of one over the other. It's also a good question to ask which one has a bigger user-base.

Comment: have you heard of doctrine (http://www.doctrine-project.org/)
or
redbean (http://www.redbeanphp.com/)

doctrine is the best one I think

Comment: Of course I've heard of them. I'm still on the verge of checking Doctrine. But I believe Doctrine is a lot bigger than what I need (small to medium sites).

Comment: phpDataMapper is built on doctrine - just makes it less weird to write I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are both implementations of the Data Mapper pattern.

Whereas phpDataMapper is a more loyal approach to the pattern, I've found it to be a bit too idealistic and strict at times.

OutletORM, on the other hand, is a lot more pragmatic and flexible (doesn't require you to extend any base classes for instance).  It is also a more mature project.

Doctrine is a great project but is huge and bloated for most simple uses.

I'd go with Outlet!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with phpDataMapper right now. Two issues I have run into so far are:

- The "documentation", which is nothing but a bunch of examples that only covers part of the functionality. No reference...! You have to go through source files and experiment if you want to use anything that is not in there (like delete()!)
- No "binary" (blob/mediumblob/binary/etc...) type. I had to add it myself!

Other things I have noticed:

- Their "entity" model is kinda useless, I mean I am just adding functions to the mapping class itself... what was that for?
- There is a "pagination" php file which looks interesting, but of course no documentation anywhere to be seen.
- the source is surprisingly small and neat, which is really good since (sorry for repeating myself) there is no doc!

All in all a rather nice experience, but not exactly a magic time saving piece of code... if you want to use it be ready to do some code reading and modification on their source.